# Android EditText maxLenght counting UTF-8 encoded characters

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, android-edittext

I need to set `maxLenght` attribute to my Android `EditText`, considering all UTF-8 characters. If i use `maxLenght` xml attribute or `InputFilter.LenghtFilter` programmatically, the limit result is not what i need.

Before sending `EditText` text to my server API, i encode it using:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(EditText.getText(), "utf-8");
```

My constant limit value is 1000 and when user types some special characters as emoticons, they seem to be considered as one letter. I'd like to set `maxLenght` according UTF-8 encoded `String`.

I tried to make some logic using `TextWatcher`, maybe is the right approach but i didn't have success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `InputFilter`, something like this:

```
private final InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            String encodedDest = URLEncoder.encode(dest.toString(), "UTF-8");
            if (encodedDest.length() > 1000) {
                return "";
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            // handle this
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

This will prevent the user from adding text to the `EditText` if its encoded length would exceed 1000 characters. (this is what you would like to achieve, if i understand correctly)

To add this filter to your `EditText`:

```
yourEditTextInstance.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use **InputFiltler.LengthFilter**

This widget automatically adjust Unicode Parsing with

`Character.isHighSurrogate()`

### Usage

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15)});
```